# tap visual white circle indicator windows 8

Tags: windows-8

In most windows 8 apps when you tap anywhere inside the app you see a white-circle tap notification.  For some reason, the notification doesn't occur in my app.  How is the indication enabled or disabled?

i tried IsHitTestVisible , but don't see anything change in my grouped item page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) has nothing to do with the white-gray tap short-animation, which is a shell feature. All apps are showing it when a touch event occurs in the context of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

This question is kinda related to my [lastest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760450/disable-touch-feedback-by-code-in-windows-8-store-apps/) so I will leave the answer here if someone tries to solve the same issue.

You can disable/enable the visual tap feedback with:

```
PointerVisualizationSettings.GetForCurrentView().IsContactFeedbackEnabled = false;
```

You can also [remove it forever in your control panel](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/how-do-i-turn-off-pen-feedback-in-windows-8/4cbfb07b-6d19-4e86-b7fe-ae97dff3e0e2).