# Disable touch feedback (by code) in windows 8/store apps?

Tags: windows-8, configuration, windows-store-apps, tap

Here is what I am talking about:

[image]

I know this visual indication is [part of the operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979585/tap-visual-white-circle-indicator-windows-8) and that it can be [disabled in the control panel](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/how-do-i-turn-off-pen-feedback-in-windows-8/4cbfb07b-6d19-4e86-b7fe-ae97dff3e0e2). However, I would like to know if it is possible to disable this definition in one application.

Comment: Good question. I just wanted to ask the same. I'm developing a game and want to display my own tap feedback visualization.

Comment: [IsContactFeedbackEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.pointervisualizationsettings.iscontactfeedbackenabled.aspx) looks promising.

Comment: @RaymondChen you can post that as an answer (so I can give you the proper points). It works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Go ahead and post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion provided by [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) I was able to found the solution for this. Just add this line in your application entry point:

```
PointerVisualizationSettings.GetForCurrentView().IsContactFeedbackEnabled = false;
```